# How can I find the location of a given item by looking at the world data?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Is there a way to search through world data to find instances of a given type of item (e.g., gold horse armor) and/or to find an item with a particular name?

My goal is to find the item's location within the in-game world, ideally with an X/Y/Z coordinate. My specific application is locating stolen items, but I can imagine other uses for such a search, for example, locating mob spawners.

Hopefully there's already a utility or technique available to help with this. But if not, some documentation on the structure of world data might do the trick, as I'm a programmer and could probably write the search myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After further research I'm reluctantly answering my own question because, as far as I can tell, there's no existing tool to do what I need.

The best option I've found is to write my own tool. It should be possible to use the Python library [pymclevel](https://github.com/mcedit/pymclevel) to write a filter for McEdit that will search for things, or possibly to use pymclevel directly without McEdit.

Unfortunately, that involves learning Python, pymclevel, and MCEdit. I'm not sure it's worth the time it would take since Bukkit plugins will address item theft, which is [the root problem I'm trying to solve](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/146544/how-can-i-find-a-thief-ideally-without-bukkit).

It seems like there should already be such a tool, or else that it wouldn't take too long for a knowledgeable person to write one. I will gleefully drop my own answer and accept another if it points me to an existing tool, or else shares the code for one.

Answer (score 1):

[MCEdit](http://www.mcedit.net/) is what you are looking for if you want to remove blocks. I don't think it does items, but something like [InvCheck](http://www.minecraftforum.net/topic/36593-invcheck-check-your-players-inventories-updated-1st-nov/) can let you browse inventories of players. Items mobs are holding is another thing entirely, and I don't know of anything that does that.

Comment: I'm not sure this actually helps with what he's trying to do, MCEdit is mostly for editing stuff.

Comment: MCEdit allows you to search for a given ID and, if you desire, replace it. Searching for things is certainly part of editing, unless that editing is purely random in nature.

Comment: Fair point, I guess.  I'm not that familiar with MCEdit.

Comment: Interesting. Once I find the ID, will MCEdit tell me where to find its location? I need to find where it is in the world, XYZ. I've expanded my question to clarify this.

Comment: On further investigation, it doesn't seem that McEdit will meet my need. As far as I can tell -- and I'd be happy to learn that I'm wrong -- it doesn't provide a way to search for and find instances of a given item type, e.g., gold horse armor, or to find an item with a particular name.